# Rotate 3d Image using Three.js or somthing else

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, html5-canvas

So I just found Three.js and it looks like a pretty cool JS library. What I'm trying to do is take a 2d image and wrap it around an object in three.js and rotate it like a 3d image. I found a few jquery libraries that offer similar functionality such as [SpriteSpin](http://spritespin.ginie.eu/index.html), but most of the discussions and resources I found seem outdated and three.js seems to beat all the jquery plugins performance wise.

So playing around with one of the examples on three.js website I manage to produce [this here](http://jsfiddle.net/TK229/). As you can see it doesn't look great.

So I'm wondering if it would be possible to flatten out a 3d image into a 2d, like the one below and wrap it around a shape in three.js and then rotate that image.

[image]

Since most of the discussion I found on how to achieve similar functionality seemed outdated, I am open to any suggestions on how to do this using more current browser based technologies. Would it be best to use WebGl or `canvas`, or maybe css3 supports this type of 3d functionality. Do I need to use three.js, or is there a smaller library that supports this functionality? Basically whats the best way to achieve this without having to loop through a bunch of images like some of the jquery libraries do.

Comment: which type of shapes do you want to support?. i have written a short axonometry class we can extend that

Comment: Shapes similar to the shape of the machine pictured in the jsfiddle(The actual machine not the cube I attempted to wrap it around). So more complex then just a single cube or single sphere.

Comment: ok the shape of the robot, but for example as you can see the body is a cuboid, a cuboid has 6 surfaces so you need 6 images for each surface to make it look realistic, this 6 images you can wrap around, you can also do that with three.js

Comment: Assuming we had the 6 images, what would be the next step? and would it be hard to support a more complex object, say 12+ surfaces?

Comment: For one thing, you need to tessellate your geometry to prevent distortion with `CanvasRenderer`: http://jsfiddle.net/TK229/1/.

Comment: Thanks for the step in the right direction. I found some new information about making maya objects work with three.js and I think that might be the direction I take for these more complex shapes.